# Template simplification

Tags: c++, templates, simplification

In one of my projects, I have the following class template hierarchy :

```
template <typename FruitType, typename ParentFilterType = void>
class filter;

template <typename FruitType> // Specialization when no parent filter is needed
class filter<FruitType, void>;
```

Where `FruitType` can be anything. Let's say it is one of `apple`, `banana` or `orange`.
So basically, a `filter` can have its own *parent* `filter` type.

I have **no control** over the `filter` code: it must remain *as it is*.

The user code usually looks like:

```
filter<apple, filter<banana, filter<orange> > > my_apple_filter;
```

Obviously, this is a bit verbose. I wondered if it is possible to get something more readable. Something like:

```
complex_filter<apple, banana, orange>::type my_apple_filter;
```

Where `complex_filter<apple, banana, orange>::type` would resolve to `filter<apple, filter<banana, filter<orange> > >`.

I tried with `complex_filter` being a `struct` template with a `typedef` inside but had no success so far. The number of template parameters should be variable (from, say, 1 to 5).

Have you ever needed something similar ? How could I do that ?

(I unfortunately cannot use C++0x but if there is a nicer solution with it, feel free to post it as it is always good to know)

Thank you.

Comment: can you use boost? boost::mpl has type vectors and also metafucntions that let you do such things

Comment: C++03 or C++0x? In C++0x you can probably use a variadic template to simplify the syntax

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: I stated in the question that I have to work with C++03 but am open to solutions in C++0x out of curiosity. I will definitely take a look at variadic templates. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: With variadic templates it is easy to just inherit from some template<class T, class... X> xxx : xxx<X...>, T{}; or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++0x, it would be variadic template.

Without C++0x, you can simply use a large list of parameters, with defaults supplied.

```
template <typename F0, typename F1 = void, typename F2 = void, typename F3 = void>
struct complex_filter
{
  typedef filter<F0, typename complex_filter<F1, F2, F3>::type> type;
};

template <>
struct complex_filter<void,void,void,void>
{
  typedef void type;
};
```

This can then be used as you wanted, and you will have to extend it manually if you ever want more parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Exactly what I wanted. (I just had to replace `class` by `struct` but I guess it was a typo because `type` wouldn't be accessible otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

what you tried should work, sort of:

```
template< class A, class B >
struct complex_filter2
{
  typedef typename filter< A, filter< B > > type;
};

template< class A, class B, class C >
struct complex_filter3
{
  typedef typename filter< A, filter< B, filter< C > > > type;
};

//etc
```

Comment: And, yes, you have to specialise for each dimension... at least pre-C++0x!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any solution that would not require to write `N` different `complex_filter` `struct` templates ? @Tomalak Geret'kal: Just for learning purposes: what does C++0x provide that helps with this regard ?

Comment: @ereOn: C++0x provides variadic templates, ie the ability of handling an a-priori unknown number of parameters.

Comment: @ereOn: Boost.Preprocessor is pretty handy to generate repetitive code like this.

Comment: @ereOn: c++0x would let you write a varadic template, with a variable number of arguments.  So you would end up writing it recursively, but you would have one template.